# Tensorflow input pipeline with queues workflow - feeding data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using the Tensorflow input pipeline via queues.

Therefore, I do:

```
images, volumes = utils.inputs(FLAGS.train_file_path, FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.num_epochs)
v_images, v_volumes = utils.inputs(FLAGS.val_file_path, FLAGS.batch_size)
```

To read the data.

```
init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())


with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Start input enqueue threads.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
    try:

        step = 0
        while not coord.should_stop():
            _, train_loss = sess.run([train_optimizer, loss])

            if step % FLAGS.val_interval == 0:
                for val_step in range(0, FLAGS.val_iter):
                        val_loss = sess.run(v_loss)
```

How can I make sure that I use the `images, volumes` and volumes for the training and the `v_images, v_volumes` for validation?

**EDIT**

```
logits = utils.inference(images, FLAGS.stacks, True)
v_logits = utils.inference(v_images, FLAGS.stacks, False)

loss = utils.get_loss(logits, volumes, FLAGS.stacks, 'train')
v_loss = utils.get_loss(v_logits, v_volumes, FLAGS.stacks, 'val')
```

**EDIT 2**

```
summary_train_op = tf.summary.merge_all('train')
summary_val_op = tf.summary.merge_all('val')

with tf.Session() as sess:

    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.train_dir + FLAGS.run, sess.graph)
    summary_writer_val = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.train_dir + FLAGS.run + FLAGS.run_val)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One technique is to build graph nodes individually for training and validation.

Consider "net" is your model graph.

```
logits_train, volumes = net(images,volumes)
logits_val, v_volumes = net(v_images, v_volumes)

loss_train = some_loss(logits_train,volumes)
train_optimizer = some_optimizer(loss_train)
```

Now, if you do,

```
1. sess.run([train_optimizer]) #It uses training data (Dequeues train data)
2. sess.run([logits_val]) #It uses validation data (Dequeues validation data )
```

I hope this helps.

## Update:

```
 _,loss_train_value, logits_train_value = sess.run([train_optimizer, loss_train,logits_train])
```

## Update 2

I am doing everything explicitly as shown below. May be there is a better way to do it.

```
loss_train_s = tf.summary.scalar("loss_train", loss_train)
acc_train_s = tf.summary.scalar("acc_train", acc_train)
loss_val_s = tf.summary.scalar("loss_val", loss_val)
train_summary_op = tf.summary.merge([loss_train_s,acc_train_s])
val_summary_op = tf.summary.merge([loss_val_s])
```

Comment: What if I additionally execute: `sess.run(summary_op)` would that dequeue anything? I have edited my answer. Do you think that would work as well?

Comment: In general when I declare a function: `d = a(b)` and then when I call: `sess.run(d)` the function a is called with parameter b?

Comment: I think Yes, It will run b as well. Based on my experiments, you have to run all those ops in one run:  sess.run([optimizer,loss, summary,etc.,]).

Comment: You can observe that behavior easily while loading images - previous script I provided. Run images, labels, key separately - it will print next next elements.

Comment: Okay so I cannot call run twice? What does `sess.run([train_optimizer])` return? How can I retrieve the loss value of the logies_val?

Comment: Ok, one last question. I have that line in my get_loss: `tf.summary.scalar('_loss_stack_' + str(stack), tmp, collections=[mode])` I thought that if this method is called twice (once for training and once for validation) with two different modes ('train' and 'val') the summary should have one plot with two loss curves one for train and one for eval. But this apparently does not work. Do you know why?

Comment: May be it confuses the summary. The way I do is, have two different summary filewriters and handle them separately (easy and clean).

Comment: See my update to get values of multiple variables at once with one run.

Comment: That is what I do as well. I have two different file writers for validation and training. So that means I will not have to set collections? But I have to set collections one for train and one for val? Could you provide an example for this as well?

Comment: And what if I wanted to retrieve the images and volumes as well I would have to do: `_, loss_list, image_batch, volume_batch, summary_str = sess.run([train_optimizer, loss, images, volumes, summary_train_op])` Is that right?

Comment: Collections : depends on your case. In my case I wanted only three variables. So, I create scalar for each and merge them.

Comment: Okay, what is the difference between collections and merging? I thought I create a variable in a collection and then merge all the variable within that collection. And each collection belongs to one file writer?

Comment: Yeah, but that does not work! I get variable names in tensor board of: loss_stack_0 and loss_stack_0_1. Do you know why something like this happens?

Comment: And then you only run sess.run() once for each validation step and once for each training step? I would like to run multiple sess.run() for validation tho :/ . Thank you anyway!

Comment: Yeah, but your losses will not be shown in the same plot in the end!!! cause you do not use the same names! Thats why!

Comment: I hope my answer helped you a bit :D